# Method that remove duplicates from a list of words in Java

Tags: java, object-oriented, strings, array, tree

Today, I took a coding challenge with this question:

Given a List of Strings, write a method removeDuplicates that removes duplicate words from the List and returns an ArrayList of all the unique words. The returned ArrayList should be lexically alphabetically.

One thing that I learned while doing this problem is a TreeSet. From my understanding it works like a set but adds elements in order.

From the code, I concluded that my time complexity would be O(n).
Can anyone offer suggestions or corrections?

```
public static ArrayList<String> removeDuplicates(List<String> input) {

    ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
    Set<String> noDups = new TreeSet<String>();

    if(input.isEmpty()){
        return array;
    }

    if(input.size() == 1){
        array.add(input.get(0));
        return array;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++){
            noDups.add(input.get(i));
    }

    return new ArrayList<String>(noDups);
}
```

Comment: By my interpretation of the requirements ("removes duplicate words … and returns an ArrayList of all the **unique** words"), `removeDuplicates(Arrays.asList("three", "two", "one", "two", "three"))` should return a list containing only "one". That's not what this code does.

Comment: @200_success That's a good point, I didn't consider that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### General advice

Prefer to declare variables by interfaces and not implementations. You don't need to specify that you use and return an `ArrayList`, specifying `List` is enough. So the first lines would be:

```
public static List<String> removeDuplicates(List<String> input) {
    List<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
    Set<String> noDups = new TreeSet<String>();
```

#### Complexity

[Javadoc for TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) says:

> This implementation provides guaranteed log(n) time cost for the basic operations (add, remove and contains).

Since you are performing a `log(n)` operation \$n\$ times, this becomes `n * log(n)`.

#### Unnecessary edge cases

This is your main code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++){
        noDups.add(input.get(i));
}
```

Now let's take a look at your special cases:

```
if(input.isEmpty()){
    return array;
}
```

We can see that this would be handled correctly by your main code.

Your other special case:

```
if(input.size() == 1){
    array.add(input.get(0));
    return array;
}
```

This too would be handled correctly by your main code.

#### Shortened code

With the above advice this would shorten your code to:

```
public static List<String> removeDuplicates(List<String> input) {
    List<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
    Set<String> noDups = new TreeSet<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++){
        noDups.add(input.get(i));
    }
    return new ArrayList<String>(noDups);
}
```

There is however one more thing we can do, and that is to use [a specific constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet-java.util.Collection-) of `TreeSet`:

```
public static List<String> removeDuplicates(List<String> input) {
    return new ArrayList<String>(new TreeSet<String>(input));
}
```